# REMOTE_PORT through WSGI

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle

I'm currently trying to get information from clients in a web application written with [bottle.py](http://www.bottlepy.org/). Bottle.py let us access the CGI variables, as defined in [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) specs through the environ variable. But these specs does not list remote_port as a mandatory nor optional variable.

```
@get('/echo/)
def echo():
    values = {}
    for i in request.environ:
        values[i] = str(request.environ[i]

    return values
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to access the remote_port information in any other mean: accessing the raw socket directly to retrieve the client_address, through bottle.py, or by any other mean

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: The client side remote port is not going to tell you anything and isn't going to be clients actual port if a proxy is a part of the connection. Can you explain what you are trying to do and can perhaps suggest a better option?

Comment: I know it's not going to give me client information on a long run, but I'd just like to understand where I can retrieve this information given the environment I have. 
Then, the side question is still how I can access the raw socket from bottly.py

Comment: It still doesn't make sense why you would want the actual 'port' number. It will be a random number with range allocated by the operating system for such client sockets. Can you clarify that what you really are after isn't REMOTE_ADDR, which some servers will supply already? That is, the IP address. That will give IP for last hops client. For before that, you may be able to use X-Forwarded-For, but using that can be problematic. As I asked, explain what you are trying to do and clarify your terms, because your stressing of the term port is confusing.

Comment: He's just asking where (if) the last remote (source) port can be found.  It's a question about how, not why, imo.  In the project I'm working on, the client's ip and port are required for legal reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a test with apache-2.4 mod_wsgi and this simple wsgi script:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield str(environ)
```

And, at least with this mod_wsgi, you get the port in `environ['REMOTE_PORT']`.

Here the full content of `environ`:

```
{  
   'mod_wsgi.listener_port':'80',
   'mod_wsgi.listener_host':'',
   'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT':'/usr/htdocs',
   'SERVER_SOFTWARE':'Apache',
   'SCRIPT_NAME':'',
   'mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile':'0',
   'mod_wsgi.handler_script':'',
   'SERVER_SIGNATURE':'<address>Apache Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>\n',
   'REQUEST_METHOD':'GET',
   'PATH_INFO':'/',
   'SERVER_PROTOCOL':'HTTP/1.1',
   'QUERY_STRING':'',
   'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.58 Safari/537.36',
   'HTTP_CONNECTION':'keep-alive',
   'SERVER_NAME':'127.0.0.1',
   'REMOTE_ADDR':'127.0.0.1',
   'mod_wsgi.queue_start':'1409123400512619',
   'mod_wsgi.request_handler':'wsgi-script',
   'apache.version':(2, 4, 10),
   'wsgi.url_scheme':'http',
   'PATH_TRANSLATED':'/opt/wsgi/wsgi.py/',
   'SERVER_PORT':'80',
   'wsgi.multiprocess':True,
   'mod_wsgi.input_chunked':'0',
   'SERVER_ADDR':'127.0.0.1',
   'DOCUMENT_ROOT':'/usr/htdocs',
   'mod_wsgi.process_group':'wsgi_local',
   'mod_wsgi.daemon_connects':'1',
   'SCRIPT_FILENAME':'/opt/wsgi/wsgi.py',
   'SERVER_ADMIN':'[no address given]',
   'wsgi.input':<mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7fd6fc5d24b0>,
   'HTTP_HOST':'127.0.0.1',
   'CONTEXT_PREFIX':'',
   'wsgi.multithread':True,
   'mod_wsgi.callable_object':'application',
   'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL':'max-age=0',
   'mod_wsgi.daemon_restarts':'0',
   'REQUEST_URI':'/',
   'HTTP_ACCEPT':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
   'wsgi.file_wrapper':<type 'mod_wsgi.FileWrapper'>,
   'wsgi.version':(1, 0),
   'GATEWAY_INTERFACE':'CGI/1.1',
   'wsgi.run_once':False,
   'wsgi.errors':<mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7fd6fc5e8930>,
   'REMOTE_PORT':'32915',
   'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE':'fr,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
   'REQUEST_SCHEME':'http',
   'mod_wsgi.version':(4,2,7),
   'mod_wsgi.script_start':'1409123400512718',
   'mod_wsgi.application_group':'127.0.0.1|',
   'mod_wsgi.script_reloading':'1',
   'mod_wsgi.request_start':'1409123400512528',
   'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING':'gzip,deflate,sdch',
   'UNIQUE_ID':'U-2ESH8AAAEAACYQU@MAAABE',
   'mod_wsgi.daemon_start':'1409123400512693'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to depend on how you serve your application.

For instance, the Django developpement server (`runserver`) won't provide you with the remote port.  Meanwhile, I was able to retrieve it with an app served on Apache and [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) and, apparently, the [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) server also provides it.

The weird thing is that, just like you said, it's not part of the [WSGI specification (PEP 333)](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/).

Comment: The CherryPy WSGI server manages directly the socket connection so can access the details of the client side of the immediate socket connection. This still isn't going to help though if there is a proxy or firewall in between, as the socket details will be that of the proxy or firewall and not the original client. Even REMOTE_ADDR has the same issues. Because of proxies and firewalls, people have used defacto headers like X-Forwarded-For, but again, it only provides IP. Use of such headers has now been formalised in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7239

Comment: I will stress again that the actual port number is also pretty meaningless anyway, as it is a dynamically assigned value which doesn't really tell you much. If someone is saying there is a requirement to log it, then they perhaps don't realise that it is of no value.

Comment: I think you made your point already, but I really don't understand why you spend so much energy trying to depict how useless this information is.  The question isn't about how relevant or not this piece of data is, and it not either about how to retrieve the request originator's ip and port (which seems to bother you big time).  It's only about *where* and *how* to read it.

Comment: If you hang around on StackOverflow long enough you will realise that a not insignificant percentage of questions are where people are asking how to solve what is the solution they perceive to be right. They never actually present the problem they were trying to solve. When you do actually manage to find out from them the problem they are trying to solve, a lot of times you will find that their idea of a solution is actually a bad idea. So in answering, you can either choose to address their solution, or you can genuinely try and help with their real problem.

Comment: This whole mentality of wanting only quick answers and not exploring properly the real underlying problem and not trusting people who are able to provide assistant is a failing of StackOverflow, You can read what I have had to say about this in the past at http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/12/let-me-google-that-for-you.html

Comment: I understand, I know the feeling, but in this case I'm perfectly sure of what I'm looking for.  I need the remote ip AND port of whatever touched my API, that's a client requirement because they want some traceability, and it's not something I have the possibility to discuss about.